# Android app missing status bar icon when accessing location services

Tags: android, location-services, android-gps

Ok this is a weird one but I maybe missing something that is obvious. I am currently accessing the user location using this function:

```
 public String[] getGeoCoords() {
    String[] geoCoords = new String[2];
    String mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return geoCoords;
        }
        Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
        if(loc== null)
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (loc == null)
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        if (loc == null)
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        geoCoords[0] = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
        geoCoords[1] = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
    }
    return geoCoords;
}
```

This returns the location as expected but the icon that you normally get when accessing the user location does not appear in the status bar.

In my Manifest I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to add this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: In my case I am getting Android icon as statusbar always. Is that you were facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing `getLastKnownLocation()` which returns last available location directly else it returns null.

The icon your are talking about comes when you request for location update like this..

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
```

so while it searches for satellites, it shows that gps icon and when it found one `onLocationChanged(Location location)` will be called with captured location.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Thank you.